# Powershell: Check files changed since a string on file

Tags: powershell

I have a file that saves the datetime of the last change with the following powershell script:

```
$path = 'C:\'
$lastchange = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
New-Item -Path $path -Name 'lastchange.txt' -ItemType "file" -Value $lastchange
```

But when I try to check the files where changed since the last run it fails and show the following message:

> Could not compare "06/09/2021 13:18:40" to "23/06/2022 01:45:16".
> Error: "Cannot convert value  "23/06/2022 01:45:16" to type
> "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."" At
> C:\lastchange.ps1:16 char:59
>
> - ... $pathfiles -Filter *.html |where {$_.lastwritetime -gt $lastchange }
> - ```
>                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure

The script I have check the files not changed since the date on file:

```
$pathfiles = 'C:\filestochange\'
$path = 'C:\'
$lastchange = Get-Content -Path  $path'lastchange.txt' -TotalCount -1
$files = Get-childitem $pathFiles -Filter *.html |where {$_.lastwritetime -gt $lastchange}
```

Comment: The format you chose to save the date string as in the file is not converting back to datetime without a little more help.  You could use [DateTime]::ParseExact to turn your date string back into a DateTime object.  I would suggest doing something different though.  When saving the date/time object to file do something like this `Get-Date | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $path\lastchange.json` and when you want to use it do `$lastchange = Get-Content $path\lastchange.json | ConvertFrom-Json`

Comment: if you change your date time string format to `-Format 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'` you won't have this issue. also, probably doesn't matter but `-Path $path'lastchange.txt'` should be `-Path  "${path}lastchange.txt"`

Comment: You changed your variable to `$lastchangeCheck` but did not update this in your `where {$_.lastwritetime -gt $lastchange}`

Comment: Do you get any errors?  Why did you choose to keep using `New-Item` to create the file instead of `Set-Content` like I suggested?  If you continue to use `New-Item` you will need to add the `-force` switch to overwrite the file if it exists otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: My mistake, I need to use only $lastchange.value to get date from json, its working now.